# How to do partial linking?

Tags: c, static, linker

In my sample C code, I use the *mysqlclient* to connect to a MySQL Server. Here is the *Makefile*.

```
example: example.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@ `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

It works fine. But the produced *example* is *dynamic*ally linked, which is not what I want. What I want do is to link against *libmysqlclient* *static*ally, while linking against other libraries *dynamic*ally, such as *libz*, *libcrypto*.

FYI. *mysql_config*'s output with *--cflags --libs*:

```
$ mysql_config --cflags --libs
-I/usr/include/mysql  -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions \
-fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE \
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv

-rdynamic -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm \
-L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I mix static and shared-object libraries when linking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954387/can-i-mix-static-and-shared-object-libraries-when-linking)

Comment: Which compiler? Related compiler agnostic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349521/what-is-incremental-linking

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I have some lightning to zap this dead post with. Maybe it'll live...

Your MySQL installation will come with two libraries, one shared, and one static. All you need to do is to explicitly link against the static library rather than the shared one. Unfortunately mysql_config probably can't help here, so you'll have to find it yourself, but it'll probably be in `/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.a'. So do this:

```
$(CC) $< -o $@ /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.a `mysql_config --cflags` \
    -lz -lcrypt ...etc...
```

(where `...etc...` is all the rest of the output that `mysql_config --libs` emits.)

The `.a` extension indicates it's a static library; we use the full pathname, not a `-lmysqlclient`, to force the compiler to use the static version not the dynamic version next to it which it will normally prefer.