# linker diagnostic: "exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link", why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Just downloaded Visual C++ and put in a hello world and its giving me the error:

> `LINK : c:\users\derek\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HelloWorld\Debug\HelloWorld.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link`

Here is the code, which doesn't result in any output...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
cout << "Hello World!";
system("PAUSE");
return 0; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make your question title stand out please. Right now it's obviously terrible.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error to me.

Comment: "Hello world" doesnt print out anywhere

Comment: @DerekSchuster you are most likely doing something else wrong, the resulting *.exe* should be created. Are you sure you are trying to run it, and not just compile?

Comment: Have you checked the output pane?

Comment: Green Arrow with Local Windows Debugger to Run

Comment: Try `cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;` to flush the output buffer.  Totally different question though.

Comment: You need someone with you to mentor you. We can't step you through learning how to use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

#### The missing output

`std::cout` is buffered, meaning that it won't display data right away - even if you write to it. To get around the problem of the application potentially not printing anything you should add a new-line after your stated output, or flush it using `std::endl` or equivalent.

```
std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; // new-line, and flush
```

---

#### The diagnostic

The diagnostic you are referring to is not an error, but a mere warning/informational message.

It's related to [incremental linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf.aspx), which is a feature used by the compiler to get around the problem of having to rebuild **every** source involved each time you compile your application. If the linker cannot find a previous compiled *exe*, or there is some other issue, it will issue the stated diagnostic as if saying; *"I need to do a full rebuild, hold on tight"*.

More can be read in the following *Q&A*:

- [**What is "incremental linking"?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3349521/1090079)

As stated by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf.aspx):

> Additionally, LINK performs a full link if any of the following
>   situations occur:
>
> - The incremental status (.ilk) file is missing. (LINK creates a new .ilk file in preparation for subsequent incremental linking.)
> - There is no write permission for the .ilk file. (LINK ignores the .ilk file and links nonincrementally.)
> - The .exe or .dll output file is missing.
> - The timestamp of the .ilk, .exe, or .dll is changed.
> - A LINK option is changed. Most LINK options, when changed between builds, cause a full link.
> - An object (.obj) file is added or omitted.

---

#### What if I don't want incremental linking, and the diagnostic?

If you'd like to disable *incremental linking* you can do so by going into the project properties and remove `/INCREMENTAL`.

See the documentation:

- [**msdn.com** - /INCREMENTAL (Link Incrementally)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf.aspx)

Comment: okay thank you, but why then does "Hello World" not appear anywhere?

Comment: Why would buffering be a problem when he has a `system("PAUSE")` call?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `PAUSE` most likely prints to *STDERR*, and not *STDOUT*; which means that the stream used by `std::cout` isn't flushed upon invoking *system("PAUSE")*.

Comment: Also, `pause` is running in a sub-process. Its writes can't flush buffers in the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

[Linker Tools Warning LNK6004](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267400%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

> The given file was either deleted or changed since the last incremental linking session. LINK attempted to correct the problem by running a full link to recreate the incremental status (.ILK) file.

Make sure the path is correct and the file exists. If nothing else works, maybe disable /INCREMENTAL on the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your expected output (`Hello World!`) is not appearing is that you are not outputting a newline as required. The output is being buffered and either never getting displayed, or getting displayed in the split second after you press a key (to dismiss the `pause`) and the window disappearing.

Add an `endl` to your `cout` call:

```
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```