# IncrediBuild increases linking time significantly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, incredibuild

I have a project and made a clean build 3 times with VS and IncrediBuild

Setup of IncrediBuild: 2 machines are compiling at once, both have around of the same performance

1. **VS compiler**

   - Compile Time: ~10min
   - Linking: ~3-4min
2. **IncrediBuild**

   - Compile Time: ~4-5min (=> as expected, approx. half time)
   - Linking: ~10min (=> unexpected, should be approx. the same time)

This is reproduceable over a few builds (I made 3 clean builds). I know, IncrediBuild can't parallelise the linking of one project, but why is linking slower with IncrediBuild compared to VS linking?

My tests show me, that I don't have any benefit using IncrediBuild and I was thinking of using a few machines to build my project to increase build speed, but if linking is that slow (and so much slower), even using 10 machines would not be a benefit for me and would not be worth the money because linking time is destroying any benefit I get from improved compile time.

I'm working in a big company and buying CPU power is cheap and no problem, but IncrediBuild costs money as well and currently it would not be worth it. Any ideas what I could try or what I could be doing wrong? I've just installed IncrediBuild and use it with default settings.

**Setup**

- Visual Studio 2017
- Windows 10 machine (agent) and Windows 7 machine (coordinator)
- 1GBit business network
- IncrediBuild 9.0.1

Comment: Maybe have you enabled link time optimization?

Comment: I've enabled incremental linking but no optimisations (no `\LTCG` or similar)

Comment: In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349521/what-is-incremental-linking, it is said that incremental linking increase linking time. Maybe incredibuild do not perform incremental linking, which would explain that MSVC has better linking time.

Comment: This (https://www.incredibuild.com/webhelp/#advanced_incredilink.html) says, you can enable this feature for VS before 2008, so assume it's working for newer versions? Can't find this explicitly stated though...

Comment: I don't know anything about incredibuild, but it is writtent "VS 2008 and earlier". I could not say I know MSVC too. The fact that you mentionned incremental linking (first time I heard about this) may be the sign that you actualy unconsciously knew the answer.

Comment: It may be this. But imho it does not make sense to take out this feature on newer versions as it makes a big difference in build times and is suggested a lot when searching for increasing link speed

Comment: Try it with IncrediBuild logging disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't expect this difference in link time when using IncrediBuild.

I would recommend trying the following:

1. Make sure you are using the Visual Studio 2017 `/Debug:FASTLINK` option.
2. If the above didn't help, see if restricting the number of PDB files IncrediBuild uses can help. Right click the IncrediBuild tray icon-> Agent Settings -> Visual Studio Builds -> Advanced, and set the "Limit concurrent PDB file instances" to 12 or below.
3. Try to temporarily disable any anti-virus software you have installed on your machine.

If these tips don't help, we'd highly appreciate if you could contact us at support@incredibuild.com so we can understand what's wrong in your environment and post a solution for the community.

Disclaimer, the write works at IncrediBuild.